# Approximate decomposition of vector

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $a,b,c$ be elements of a normed space such that $a+b=c$ and $\lVert a\rVert\leq\lVert c\rVert/2+\varepsilon$ and $\lVert b\rVert\leq\lVert c\rVert/2+\varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon>0$. What would be a good upper bound on $\lVert a-b\rVert$?

It seems very intuitive that the difference of these two vectors should be small but I fail miserably at using the triangle inequality to show so. Or is my intuition wrong?

It is clear that $\lVert a\rVert,\lVert b\rVert\geq \lVert c\rVert/2-\varepsilon$ but this doesn't help immediately.

Comment: A MathJax oddity: I thought the "$\le$" looked improperly close to the thing to is left in $\lVert a\lVert \le\text{etc.}$.  So I clicked on "edit" and found \lVert a\lVert a \le etc., with \lVert on both sides.  I changed it to \lVert a\rVert \le etc. and now you see $\lVert a\rVert \le\text{etc.}$ with proper spacing. This one I shouldn't really call an oddity maybe.... $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your intition is leading you in a wrong direction. Consider $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the $1-$norm $\left\|\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{pmatrix}\right\|_1=|x_1|+|x_2|$.

Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and $a=\begin{pmatrix}n\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $b=\begin{pmatrix}0\\n\end{pmatrix}$, $c=\begin{pmatrix}n\\n\end{pmatrix}$. Then $$\|a\|_1=\|b\|_1=\frac{1}{2}\|c\|_1 = n,$$ but $$\|a-b\|_1 = 2n,$$ i.e. there is no upper bound.

I'm not sure for which norms you can generalize this kind of argument.